# Bean configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans configured in spring following way. I am giving the pseudo code as below

```
<beans>
    <bean id="a" class="Employee">
        <property name="b" ref="b" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="b" class="Department">
        <property name="a" ref="a" >
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What happens in this case. I think the configuration works fine. Correct me if i am wrong.

I would like to know if i can configure beans in such a way. If it not proper then what exception it throws

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: The problem is i am facing lot of issues configuring spring currently. There is no set up ready to execute it

Answer (score 0):

You lack a closing quote on `Employee` class. Also, use a ref attribute to attach another bean to a bean's property. Here's the fix:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="a" class="Employee">
       <property name="b" ref="b" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="b" class="Department">
       <property name="a" ref="a" />
   </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: That was i typo. I would like to know if i can configure beans in such a way. If it not proper then what exception it throws

Comment: The <property> tag should be inside the <bean> tag.